# Ошибка при запуске программы в exe из qt

Tags: qt, exe

Мой проект не может запуститься в ехе. Изначально я пользовался этой статьёй http://blog.harrix.org/article/1015 при запуске, но у меня появилась в конце такая ошибка -? event@Widget@MEAA_NPEAVQevent@@@Z не найдена в библиотеке DLL *Путь к папке с релизной версией*

Comment: Вы какой екзешник собрали дебажный, или релизный?

Comment: Релизный собрал

Comment: Похоже у вас пути для запуска не указывают на необходимые либы. В переменной окружения path должно быть как-то так `C:\Qt\Qt5.12.1\5.12.1\mingw73_64\bin`. Это на моей системе, у вас имена папок могут отличаться, но суть таже

Comment: Можете сказать , где находится эта переменная?